# How to sort a column based on specific text in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, sorting

I have the following:

```
=sort(filter('CASES LIST'!C:R,('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="admission")+('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="pending")+('CASES LIST'!Q:Q="PCI")),16,true)
```

but I want to sort in the following sequence:

`Pending` first
`admission` second
`PCI` third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following query formula (adjusting ranges to your needs), instead of the filter one you already use.

```
=QUERY(sort(P1:R,match(Q1:Q,{"Pending","admission","PCI"},0),TRUE), 
               "where Col2 matches 'admission|PCI|pending' ",0)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)
- [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: What do you mean as a must?